# Specifying command line arguments from the command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

How do you specify command line arguments from the Visual Studio Command line prompt?

Let's say I want to start my Main with an array of letters or something. In Visual Studio 2010  I'd go through the debugging tab but I have no idea how to do that with the command line prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add it after the name of your exe:

```
myProg.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: No need to, now you will know :)